# How to analyze each methods within query execution plan AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

While trying to see the difference between athena query engine V2 and V3. I am looking at the difference in their query execution plan of simple left join query. Overall architecture seems the same however in each method(box when you click "explain" in athena console) there are slight differences and I want to know how exactly they are different.

For example within "ScanFilterProject" V3 contain additional parameter {"projectLocality":"Local"} while V2 does not. What is the difference and where are some references for analyzing each method within query plan?

Comment: Can you add your full query plans to the question.